# Doctrine createQuery Uncaught exception

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, orm

I trying use SELECT by using doctrine orm. Database: postgresql

```
$dql = 'SELECT name_serial FROM serial';
$query = $entityManager->createQuery($dql);
$query->setMaxResults(30);
$result = $query->getResult();
echo json_encode($result);
```

But have exception:

```
Uncaught Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: SELECT name_serial FROM serial in /home/{username}/Serials/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:41
```

Somebody can help?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the code in a try-catch block and printing the actual exception message? Are you sure your entity is called `serial` or maybe `AppBundle:Serial` or something?

Comment: I tried wrapping the code in a try-catch and get result:

[Semantical Error] line 0, col 24 near 'serial': Error: Class 'serial' is not defined.

I checked my request in pgadmin and it has not any errors.